# Javascript - Cannot retrieve firebase data that called inside a function

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I'm on project with firebase database. I'm trying to retrieve data 2 times. First time is work well, but the second one is not work as it will be. Here's my code:

```
<script>
    // Initialize Firebase
    var config = {
        apiKey: "-------------",
        authDomain: "-------------",
        databaseURL: "-------------",
        projectId: "-------------",
        storageBucket: "-------------",
        messagingSenderId: "-------------"
    };
    firebase.initializeApp(config);

    // Get a reference to the database service
    var location = firebase.database().ref('loc/');

    location.once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
        init(snapshot);
    });
</script>
```

And then in different script tag, I place all of my function

```
<script>
    function init(snapshot) {
        console.log(snapshot.location) //there's no permission issue here

        var onChangeHandler = function(name) {
            myFunction(name);
        };

        //to get input from user
        $('.drc').click(function(){
            var text = $(this).text();
            onChangeHandler(text);
        });

    }

    function myFunction(name) {

        var find = firebase.database().ref('routes/'+name);

        //the permission issue start here
        routes.once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
            var routesName = snapshot.name;
            console.log(routesName);
        });

    }

</script>
```

of course I've set the rule:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != false",
    ".write": "auth != false"
  }
}
```

my error:

> Uncaught (in promise) Error: permission_denied at /routes/AL : Client doesn't have permission to access the desired data.

What's wrong with my code? Why I cannot acces it for the second time?

Comment: You should first of all consider using snapshot.val().name instead of snapshot.name, but I do not see any issue here from the permission side. Why not try `"auth.uid != null"` or just `true`?

Comment: Are you signed in via Firebase Auth when executing this code? Because your security rules are currently set to deny access to any client that isn't signed in.